# SemanticUI - set focus on textarea in Modal

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

Using a SemanticUI modal.
I want an event to fire that shows the modal, then sets .focus() and .select() on a textarea in the form (it's not the first control in the form).

Does not appear to fire when I have this:

```js
$('.ui.modal').modal('setting', {
      autofocus: false,
      onVisible: function() {
        $('.ui.modal textarea').focus();
        $('.ui.modal textarea').select();
      }
    }).modal('show');
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Autofocus attribute? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_autofocus.asp

Answer (score 1):

Appearently, `autofocus` option fires after any other focus is set, be it html attributes or `onVisible` callback, and overrides it.

`<textarea autofocus="true">` mensioned by [Cas Nouwens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2738980/cas-nouwens) will just set focus on textarea element, but it won't let you select its text. If it is the desired behaviour, you can stick to this solution and remove `modal('setting' ,{...})`  completely.

Otherwise, I found a (quite dirty, I admit) workaround by wrapping your code in a tiny timeout. The transition is *almost* invisible.

```
$('.ui.modal').modal('setting', {
  autofocus: false,
  onVisible: function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.ui.modal textarea').focus();
      $('.ui.modal textarea').select();
    }, 10);
  }
}).modal('show');
```

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/akhanov/fago708n/1/)